# Blob URL with UTF-16LE encoding

Tags: javascript, blob, utf-16

I have this string `%22%00%41%00%22%00%09%00%22%00%42%00%22%00` which is the UTF-16LE equivalent of `"A"\t"B"`. (The `\t` is a Tab char.)

I am trying to construct a Blob and then a URL for it, but the output isn't decoded to proper entities.

```
var blob=new Blob([stringHere],{type:'text/csv;charset=UTF-16LE;'});
var blobUrl=URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Is there anyway to tell the Blob the string encoding so that it looks properly when opened in Excel (in this particular case)?

I need UTF-16LE, otherwise using UTF-8 will result in Excel no parsing the .csv file properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need a utf-16 le bom in the file, which you can't do with a string in js, so you'll have to use a byte array. See example below

```
var stringHere = '%ff%fe%22%00%41%00%22%00%09%00%22%00%42%00%22%00';
var byteArray = [];
stringHere.replace(/([0-9a-f]{2})/gi, function(d){
    byteArray.push(parseInt(d, 16));
});
var blob=new Blob([new Uint8Array(byteArray)],{type:'text/csv;charset=UTF-16LE;'});
var blobUrl=URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: Hi Musa, thanks. That doesn't seem to output UTF-16LE though. Like you said, I need that encoding for Excel to interpret CSVs properly. BOM is for non-ASCII chars. It seems to me the `type` thing only looks at MIME Type and ignores the charset specified.

Comment: @Francisc I tried it and it worked for me, if you put the blob url in the browser it will download the file, just give it a csv extension and open it with excel.

Comment: And you actually see "A" and "B" in different columns?

Comment: You're right, it does work. I must have done a mistake when I first tested.

Comment: Hm, how would you go about converting `%22` to `0x22` for example?

Comment: Awesome, thank you. After playing with this a bit it seems it's enough to just do toString(16) on each UTF-8 char too.

Comment: Do you think using `Uint8Array` could make converting from UTF-8 to UTF-16LE first unnecessary?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, I see urlencoded utf-16 le not utf-8. Is it utf-8 and you convert it to `urlencoded utf-16 le`?

Comment: I have the UTF-8 encoded string. `"A"\t"B"` which I convert to UTF-16LE (because of Excel). The replace function you wrote seems to like an extra step because of my initial conversion and I was wondering if using UTF-8 and Uint8Array I could get away without the extra to UTF-16LE conversion.

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. But thing to remember, each entry in the Uint8Array represents a byte not a character. A utf-8 character can be 1-4 bytes long. The url encoding encoded each byte which made it easy to convert it to an typed array.